# Excel formulas Timestamp

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vba

Guys I'm having a problem.
In the current sheet.
In F1 i'm using the follow formula for date the current date.

```
=TEXT(NOW(), "dd-mm-yyyy")
```

Sheet will auto refresh every 1 min.

Dates in each cell (A4:A53)13-11-2017,14-11-2017 date going down. 
Using and if statement to see if current date is true then insert (B1) if false then write nothing. Current formula i am using.

`=IF(F1=A4:A53,"B1,"")`

It is always saying dates are not true, always false. Even if they are true.
Any advise please

[image]

Comment: How are the cells formatted? As date-time? Are they formatted with the same date-time format?

Comment: Yip, made sure all cells formatted as date. same for format custom. dd-mm-yyyy.

Comment: =IF(F1=A4:A53,"true","false") F1 is were current date is Date running down must be equal to current date

Comment: `F1=A4:A53` will never be `TRUE` - you are comparing a single value to a range...

Comment: But even if i do it on the current cell for example =if(F1=A4,"true","false") still is false

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your formula `=IF(F1=A4:A53,"true","false")`, the condition `F1=A4:A53` will **always** be `FALSE` since you are comparing a single cell's value to a **range**. Also, try casting the cell values to a date using the `DATE` function.

Try changing your formula to:

```
=IF(DATE(F1)=DATE(A4),"true","false")
```

Where `$A$1` is the cell with today's date.

Comment: Thanks for this. Solved my issue. Statement are displaying true values. If i'm doing the same thing with time which is the Best formula to call current time. To used with another if statement?

Comment: Can you post is as another question and post me the question link here?

Comment: Will have to wait 2 days. Will send you the link then. Thanks so much.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect that the dates in the column are actual date values while the one you are creating from the formula is a text value. As such, they will never be equal.

To have them equal, you should change your formula become `=INT(NOW())` (to remove the time from the date and time value) or use `=TODAY()` (which only gives the date and not the time).

Either that, or change your comparison formula to:

```
=IF(F1*1=A4*1,"true","false")
```

In most cases, excel will be able to convert a 'text-ified' date when an arithmetic operation is applied on it. If you get errors, then it means excel was not able to convert the date and you should use a format that your excel understands.